# How can I start the gnome-terminal with multiple tabs with always the same title and history?

Tags: shell, configuration, tabs, gnome-shell

I want to start the bash with 4 tabs, having different titles. In all of them I'm working in different directories so it would be useful if I can cd to different paths.

Now it would be also great to save the history separately for every tab. So that every tab only remembers the commands I ran on it, even after a reboot.

Currently I have a script which starts gnome-terminal with 4 tabs.

```
gnome-terminal --geometry=150x50 --tab --title="src" -e "bash -c \"cd "~/path/to/src";exec bash\"" --tab --title="first test" -e "bash -c \"cd "~/path/to/single-test-dir";exec bash\"" --tab --title="test3" -e "bash -c \"cd "~/path/to/testdir";exec bash\"" --tab --title="test4" -e "bash -c \"cd "~/path/to/somewhere";exec bash\""
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you can use a gnome-terminal custom command for each profile, for example

```
bash -c 'PROFILE=default_profile exec bash'
```

or

```
bash -c 'PROFILE=screen_profile exec screen -U'
```

or similar.

Then in ~/.bashrc

```
if [[ -n $PROFILE ]]; then
    HISTFILE=~/.bash_history."$PROFILE"
fi
```

[source of the answer.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/94439/can-i-create-a-separate-bash-history-file-for-each-terminal-profile)